# Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GraddleWrapperMain

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle, android-emulator, chocolatey

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 945 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

```
at makeError (C:\Users\Asad\OneDrive\ڈیسک ٹاپ\mobileappclass\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\Asad\OneDrive\ڈیسک ٹاپ\mobileappclass\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Asad\OneDrive\ڈیسک ٹاپ\mobileappclass\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Asad\OneDrive\ڈیسک ٹاپ\mobileappclass\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```